# Is AngularJS a good option for building a catalog page of E-Commerce site based on CakePHP

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, slim

I am considering to use AngularJS for building my catalog on my E-Commerce platform based on CakePHP. I plan to query database using Slim REST API in CakePHP. [This is what the catalog](https://paytm.com/shop/g/home-and-kitchen/home-furnishing/kitchen-linen) would look like.

I am not sure if I should use AngularJS. If I should can someone please help me to know why I should use it and how it shall be a benefit to use AngularJS in building such catalog page?

Comment: You're using the Slim framework inside Cake? I'd stick with one or the other if I were you - you might be in danger of expanding your support cost more than can be justified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally have used AngularJS, EmberJS, HandlebarsJS and dabbled in some other things. In my humble opinion AngularJS is one of the best frameworks to use. It is backed by Google and heavily used in the web development community. After getting stuck once on a bug in Angular, I emailed one of the AngularJS creators, and received a response from him within a couple days. I've found that although the learning curve isn't the easiest, its easier to learn than many of the other frameworks I've played with.

I quote angular's website:

> HTML is great for declaring static documents, but it falters when we try to use it for declaring dynamic views in web-applications. AngularJS lets you extend HTML vocabulary for your application. The resulting environment is extraordinarily expressive, readable, and quick to develop.

Personally I have found that using angular has drastically reduced the amount of code that I've had to write to get a web-application to work in JavaScript. The current company I work at uses Angular to run one of their e-commerce sites. Mobile integration is excellent.

Just looking at your link quickly, that is a very doable application in angular. You'll need a RESTful webservice to get the data, but everything else can be rather easily handled using Angular on the front end. [Here is a robust tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat) making a full featured app in angular, I think it should give you a good idea of what is possible with angular.